# Django TinyMce doesn't show in admin page

Tags: django, django-admin, tinymce

I install django-tinymce application in my Django project. my models is

```
from tinymce.models import HTMLField    
class Article(models.Model):
        category=models.ForeignKey(Category)
        title= models.CharField(max_length=200)
        content= HTMLField()
        createDate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

and i added `(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),` in my urls.py. just like installation document said (http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html). And place tiny_mce folder from this application i download into my media root.
But when i open my admin page, and add Article, my page just like this:
[image]

The TinyMce doesn't show, and my content even can't edit. What happen to me?

I fixed my problems, just put all js files in media root. but when i open my admin page ,
my editor show like this:[image] There just has few editors plugin in this textarea, where is the others like image upload?

Comment: You did this part? http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#testing

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres i try to do that. but i confuse about this: `Setup environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE:export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='testtinymce.staticfiles_settings'` what's this mean? Is this a command? How could i do this?

Comment: ah paste it in `console`

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres it shows `'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Windows really? also you can see the errors on the browser with `F12` and reloading the page.